# Formula for finding Conditional Variance

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

I am working on a problem that asks for Var(Y|X=1)

Is this the same as E(Y$^2$|X=1) - $\big($E(Y|X=1)$\big)$$^2$

Comment: You should think of conditioning on an event as giving the random variable $Y$ a new distribution. So the conditional variance of $Y$ given this event is just the usual notion of variance but for the new distribution $Y$. In particular, the usual formula $\text{Var}(Y) = E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2$ holds, but for the new distribution the expectations are with respect to the new distribution and are usually notated by $E[\cdot \mid X = 1]$.

Comment: So just to clarify, by calculating out the formula above that will lead to the same answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the notation $E( \cdot \mid X = 1)$ signifies the integral with respect to the measure $\mu( \cdot ) = \dfrac{\mathbf{P}(\cdot \cap \{X = 1\})}{\mathbf{P}(X = 1)}.$ Hence, by denoting $a = \int Y d\mu,$ we have $\mathbf{V}\mathrm{ar}(Y) = \|Y - a\|_{\mathscr{L}^2(\mu)}^2=\int(Y-a)^2 d\mu = \int Y^2 d\mu - a^2.$ So **yes**.